# I can't get list from wifi scan result

Tags: android

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

    **//My Activity class** 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnScan,btnSend;
ListView lvPeers ;

ArrayList<String> listWifi ;
WifiManager wifiManager ;
BroadcastReceiveWifi receiveWifi;
List<ScanResult> listResult;


public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public TextView txtState ;

private void AnhXa()
{
    btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
    lvPeers = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPeers);
    txtState = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTest);
    btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    listWifi = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AnhXa();
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnScan.setOnClickListener(this);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);



    if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()==true)
    {
        ScanWifi();
    }



}


public void ScanWifi()
    {
        receiveWifi = new BroadcastReceiveWifi();
        registerReceiver(this.receiveWifi,new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifiManager.startScan();

    }


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnScan:
            if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == true) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

            }

            else
            if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()==false)
            {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                ScanWifi();
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btnSend:
               HospotWifi("DataTransfer","12345678");
            break;
    }

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiveWifi);

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(receiveWifi,new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();

}

class BroadcastReceiveWifi extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            listResult = wifiManager.getScanResults();

            for (int i =0; i<listResult.size();i++)
            {
                listWifi.add(listResult.get(i).SSID);
            }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listWifi);
            lvPeers.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,listResult.size()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're running the code on android 6.0+, you'll need to request for permissions at runtime.

Comment: I run it on android 5.0. Help me, please !